# How to call ms-access function from C#?

Tags: function, module, ms-access-2007

I have written an ms-access function in a module called ‘StripLead’. I made a single line procedure called ‘CallFunction’. Now when I call this procedure from ms-access it works fine. But when I call this procedure from C# I get error:

> Undefined function 'Striplead' in expression.

Ms-access module code:

```
Public Function StripLead(pstrPhrase As String) As String
  Dim strFirstWord As String
  Dim strReturn As String
  Dim intPos As Integer

  strReturn = pstrPhrase
  intPos = InStr(pstrPhrase, " ")
  If intPos > 0 Then
    strFirstWord = Left$(pstrPhrase, intPos - 1)
    Select Case strFirstWord
      Case "A", "An", "The"
      strReturn = Right$(pstrPhrase, Len(pstrPhrase) - intPos)
    End Select
  End If

StripLead = strReturn
End Function
```

Ms-access procedure "CallFunction"(sql view):

```
SELECT Customers.ID, Striplead([ContactName]) AS a FROM Customers;
```

C# code:

```
   public void CallStoredProcedure(string NewQry)
       {
           try
           {
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "CallFunction";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = connection;

                using (OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    adp.Fill(tbl);
                }
            }

         }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw;   
        }
    }
```

Please suggest whether the approach is incorrect. Or else, if there is a way to make call to ms-access function from C# to fetch data.
My aim is to fetch modified data from ms-access and fill the datagrid in C#.

Answer (score 3):

Access offers the ability to call user-defined VBA functions from SQL queries, but that capability is restricted to queries that are made from *within the Microsoft Access application itself*. That is because the VBA functions require the Access application's infrastructure (specifically, the VBA "Expression Service") to execute.

In your case you might be able to run a "real" *Access* query from within your C# code using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access` but that would give you a `DAO Recordset` object, and fiddling around with that to work with an `OleDbDataAdapter` could well be more trouble than it's worth (if it is possible at all).

You'll probably just be better off to re-create the VBA function logic in C#.