# How can I select from ms access query that uses an internal vba function?

Tags: c#, vba, ms-access, oledb

I have a query in a MS access database that I'm selecting from it in a c# application.
in this query I needed to make a column that shows the maximum of two values but since ms access doesn't have this so I had to write my own function in vba like this:

```vb
Public Function Maximum(ParamArray FieldArray() As Variant)
' Declare the two local variables.
Dim I As Integer
Dim currentVal As Variant

' Set the variable currentVal equal to the array of values.
currentVal = FieldArray(0)

' Cycle through each value from the row to find the largest.

For I = 0 To UBound(FieldArray)
   If FieldArray(I) > currentVal Then
      currentVal = FieldArray(I)
   End If
Next I

' Return the maximum value found.
Maximum = currentVal
End Function
```

it works perfectly when i'm running the query in ms access but when I try to select this query from C# I get this error:

> Undefined function 'Maximum' in expression.

so any solution ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call ms-access function from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043939/how-to-call-ms-access-function-from-c)

Comment: DMax and Max work outside of MS Access. Why have you written a function?

Answer (score 0):

Without using some type of automation, you can't access that function.
The simplest thing would be to put the records into a datatable, add another column to it and loop through the rows, populating the column with the max value, using a C# function.